# Application install problem

Tags: android

when I am trying to install my application apk into suitable emulator the followingerrors are coming

C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb install TeslaWorldNet.apk
1583 KB/s (2911477 bytes in 1.796s)
Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/TeslaWorldNet.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

What is the problem .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You just have to read the error message... it clearly says: `INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK`. So, you are trying to install an application with a SDK version that is superior to the SDK installed on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the version of the emulator configuration is same or more than the value specified in  tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your device SDK is compatible with your app SDK

Open the Manifest file and check the following:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

However, sometimes changing it from the manifest file will still give you the same error.

If this doesn't work: Create New App, and then copy your files to the new app, make sure when you create the app, the SDK matches your requirement